# DatePicker is not working in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have written a code in React.js for Datepicker but it's not working :

```
var DatePicker = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        currentDate: Moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    };
},
prev: function () {
    var dateForHandler = new Date(this.state.currentDate);
    var dateForState = new Date(this.state.currentDate);
    this.props.dateHandler(dateForHandler.setDate(dateForHandler.getDate() - 7));
    this.setState({currentDate: Moment(dateForState.setDate(dateForState.getDate() - 7)).format('MM/DD/YYYY')});

},
next: function () {
    var dateForHandler = new Date(this.state.currentDate);
    var dateForState = new Date(this.state.currentDate);
    this.props.dateHandler(dateForHandler.setDate(dateForHandler.getDate() + 7));
    this.setState({currentDate: Moment(dateForState.setDate(dateForState.getDate() + 7)).format('MM/DD/YYYY')});

},
render: function () {
    var currentDate = this.state.currentDate;
    return (
        <div className="col-md-12 text-center mar_top_bottom">
            <Button text="" key="prev" click={this.prev} css="arrow_icon_backg arrow_left_icon pull-left"/>
            <p className="text_padding">{Moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')==currentDate?'This Week':'Week of '+currentDate}</p>
            <Button text="" key="next" click={this.next} css="arrow_icon_backg arrow_right_icon pull-right"/>
        </div>
    );
},
componentDidMount: function () {

},
componentWillUnmount: function () {

}
```

I have created a contrl DatePicker.js. the above code is written on DatePicker.js.

And i am calling this datepicker on js page then datepicker will not come.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a copy/paste error, but the code above is missing the closing brackets `})`.
Also, I would recommend showing how the code is being called.

Comment: I am calling code in this way: <DatePicker
    selected={this.state.startDate}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>

Comment: have you exported the `DatePicker` from this file ?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Can you paste your whole file please? Including `import`/`require` statements.

Comment: var React = require('react');
var Button = require('../Controls/Button');
var Moment = require('moment');

Comment: have you exported the `datepicker` from `datepicker` file like `export default DatePicker `??

Comment: Yes, I have exporetd from DatePicker.js

Comment: can you show that how you are exporting ?

Comment: var React = require('react');
var DatePicker = require('react-datepicker');
var moment = require('moment');

Comment: var DatePicker = require('../Controls/DatePicker');

Comment: this is how you are importing datpicker in other files, how you are exporting from datepicker file ? so that it will be available in another components. when you write this: `var DatePicker = require('../Controls/DatePicker');` it will search what you have exported from `DatePicker`, this is what i am asking.